# How do I transfer multiple files using Ruby Net::SSH.start?

Tags: ruby

I want to copy all files from remote host `/root/files/*.log`to my current directory - `./files1/`

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/scp'

Net::SSH.start( scp_hostname, scp_username, :keys => scp_keys, :timeout => 360 ) do |ssh|
    ssh.scp.download!( '/root/files/*.log', './files1/' )
    ssh.exec!( .. )
    ssh.exec!( .. )
end
```

I got an exception :

```
caught exception SCP did not finish successfully (1): scp: /root/files/*.log: No such file or directory
```

But it worked when I copied a specific file

```
ssh.scp.download!( '/root/files/myfile.log', './files1/' )
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using net sftp for this as it allows globing directory which is more elegant. Here:

```
require 'net/sftp'
Net::SFTP.start( scp_hostname, scp_username, :keys => scp_keys, :timeout => 360 ) do |sftp|
    sftp.dir.glob("/remote/path", "*.log") do |file|
      sftp.download!( "/remote/path/#{file.name}", "./files1/#{file.name}" )
    end
end
```

or with ssh you can use the following trick:

```
Net::SSH.start( scp_hostname, scp_username, :keys => scp_keys ) do |ssh|
  logfiles = ssh.exec!( 'ls /remote/path/*.log' ).split
  logfiles.each { |file|
    ssh.scp.download!( file, file )
  }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use without any ruby gem. Using [scp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) command.

**Basic syntax of SCP**

```
scp source_file_name username@destination_host:destination_folder
```

Or

```
scp username@remote:/file/to/send /where/to/put
```

**Edit Update**

Just remove `timeout` option will help you! and use  `:recursive => true` option.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/scp'

Net::SSH.start( scp_hostname, scp_username, :keys => scp_keys ) do |ssh|
    ssh.scp.download!( '/root/files/*.log', './files1/', :recursive => true )
    ssh.exec!( .. )
    ssh.exec!( .. )
end
```

Hope this help you !